# How to read/write a location from/to a json file with Rascal

Tags: rascal

We are using the `lang::json::IO::writeJSON()` function to serialize some data to a JSON file.

This worked great until we tried to store a method location.
A location contains the start line and column between the `<` and `>` characters, which is apparently not a problem to write to a JSON file (it is written as a string, not attempting to parse anything).

The problem starts when you want to do use `lang::json::IO::readJSON` with a location stored as a string. Rascal tries to parse the string as an object, and fails.

eg:

```java
rascal>map[str, loc] metrics = ();
map[str, loc]: ()
rascal>metrics["test"] = a;
map[str, loc]: ("test":|project:///rascal/bla.java|(0,0,<0,0>,<1,0>))
rascal>writeJSON(|file:///tmp/test.json|,metrics);
ok
rascal>metrics = readJSON(#map[str, loc], |file:///tmp/test.json|);
|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(925,2980,<30,0>,<58,160>): IO("could not parse URI:$.test")
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(925,2980,<30,0>,<58,160>))
        at readJSON(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(3873,30,<58,128>,<58,158>))
```

Is there a better way to serialize/unserialize `loc` instances to a JSON file?

Appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to write the locations as JSon objects rather than strings, like so:

```
writeJSON(|file:///tmp/test.json|,metrics, unpackedLocations=true);
```

When reading back the file, the parser will see that it has to convert the object back to a Rascal Source location by interpreting the names of each field.

```
rascal>l = |project://x/y/z|(10,10,<1,2>,<3,4>);
loc: |project://x/y/z|(10,10,<1,2>,<3,4>)

rascal>writeJSON(|home:///example.txt|, [l], unpackedLocations=true)
ok

rascal>println(readFile(|home:///example.txt|))
[{"scheme":"project","authority":"x","path":"/y/z","offset":10,"length":10,"begin":[1,2],"end":[3,4]}]

rascal>readJSON(#list[loc], |home:///example.txt|)
list[loc]: [|file:///y/z|(10,10,<1,2>,<3,4>)]

ok
```

Comment: Actually, after trying it out, (and having to restart the terminal a few times), this does not seem to work. The content of the JSON file is identical regardless of the value of unpackedLocations ? And reading the file fails with the same error message.

Comment: Ok thanks; maybe a typo in the parameter name? Otherwise I'll go and have a debug session.

Comment: it works for me.. perhaps this is due to a "refresh" issue in Eclipse? The eclipse file system is sometimes out-of-date with the actual file system and "refresh" fixes that.

Comment: I restarted everything multiple times. Each time the same issue. I deleted the file so I'm sure that is not causing any issue: ```rascal>writeJSON(|file:///tmp/test.json|,metrics, unpackedLocations=true);
ok
rascal>metrics = readJSON(#map[str, loc], |file:///tmp/test.json|);
|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(925,2980,<30,0>,<58,160>): IO("could not parse URI:$.test")
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(925,2980,<30,0>,<58,160>))
        at readJSON(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(3873,30,<58,128>,<58,158>))
```

Comment: The code works fine on my team mates workstation running Linux. Might be a problem with my installation. I'll consider it resolved. Thanks again Jurgen!

Comment: Final closing comment on this: After upgrading rascal to the version 0.16.2 in my Eclipse, it worked. Whether that was the real problem or not I do not know, but I can say at least now that it is working fine.

Comment: Ok that's cool. There is a pre-release of 0.22.0 floating around which could also help in some ways. Get it from github actions of the usethesource/rascal-eclipse project. Thanks for your patience anyway.